# Mocking / stubbing C# record types in a unit test

Tags: design, c#, unit-testing

I have a series of `record` types in my C# project that I use with JSON.Net to deserialize json data.

```cs
public record RadarrMetadata(
    IReadOnlyCollection<string> CustomFormats
);

public record SonarrMetadata(
    IReadOnlyCollection<string> ReleaseProfiles
);

public record JsonPaths(
    RadarrMetadata Radarr,
    SonarrMetadata Sonarr
);

public record RepoMetadata(
    JsonPaths JsonPaths
);
```

I need to "mock" instances of `RepoMetadata` to feed it into another object as part of its unit test suite. My solution right now is to create `RepoMetadata` objects directly, like so:

```cs
[Test, AutoMockData]
public void Directory_separators_are_normalized(
    [Frozen] IRepoMetadataParser metadataParser,
    RepoPathsFactory sut)
{
    var metadata = new RepoMetadata(
        new JsonPaths(
            new RadarrMetadata(new[] {"foo/bar\\dir"}),
            new SonarrMetadata(new[] {""})
        )
    );

    metadataParser.Deserialize().Returns(metadata);
    var result = sut.Create();
    result.RadarrCustomFormatPaths.Should().NotContain(x => !x.FullName.Contains(_oppositeSlash));
```

However, I do not like manually constructing `RepoMetadata` for these reasons:

- If the surface of this object and its properties changes later, this test will break even though those particular properties have nothing to do with what this test is trying to verify.
- Sort of a continuation of the above point: I have to create and pass in `SonarrMetadata` even though this type is inconsequential to the test.

One way I could solve this is by defining an interface for every `record` class, including nested types. Then I could use AutoFixture to create the object and just specify a return value for the properties I care about using NSubsitute:

```cs
[Test, AutoMockData]
public void Directory_separators_are_normalized(
    [Frozen] IRepoMetadata metadata,
    RepoPathsFactory sut)
{
    metadata.JsonPaths.Radarr.CustomFormats.Returns(new[] {"foo/bar\\dir"});
    var result = sut.Create();
    result.RadarrCustomFormatPaths.Should().NotContain(x => !x.FullName.Contains(_oppositeSlash));
}
```

However, it "feels wrong" to create this many interfaces (one per ORM type). I don't know if I'm on the right track. However, I really love how clean and concise the above alternative is when I introduce interfaces:

- Test is cleaner / more concise
- I don't need `IRepoMetadataParser` (or other intermediate objects)
- I don't need to redundantly construct properties that I don't care about in `RepoMetadata` which makes this test less fragile when the data structure changes later to add more fields.

Is my approach with interfaces the best way? Should I go with mutable types instead (add setters to the properties)? The immutable types work great for the actual business logic, but the unit tests are troublesome because of it.

Comment: It takes two minutes to fix up your unit tests so that they function again.

Comment: Is AutoFixture not able to generate records directly?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sure, two minutes today. But what if I have dozens more of these tests? What if the object grows later and two minutes becomes 30 minutes? But beside all of that, your point is not relevant to my question.

Comment: @Caleth Yes, it can, but then how do I modify the properties I care about? There's no easy way to do that unless I make the properties mutable. There are workarounds, like those documented in the link posted below. But I wasn't particularly happy with those solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938972/how-to-build-nested-property-with-autofixture

Comment: It actually is relevant.  Software development is an exercise in tradeoffs; will it take more time to maintain your unit tests or to maintain those interfaces?

Comment: The examples in that link seem like they would be improved with `record`s and `with` expressions, especially `Lens`es.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The interfaces idea is one possible solution. But what about others? That's why I'm posting here. To discover more solutions and more tradeoffs and make an educated decision on which approach is better. It's possible that I end up changing nothing. Your comment isn't relevant because it doesn't directly respond to my question; I am not measuring relevance in terms of software development at large.

Comment: @Caleth Thanks; the link I posted talks about Lenses, but I don't see native support for it. So I don't know what you are referring to with `Lens`. And `with` is something I'd like to use, but I don't think there's a syntax for it to modify properties of nested records. e.g. something like `metadata with { JsonPaths.Radarr.CustomFormats = new[] {} }`

Comment: It's [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bogUxk). That answer defines the class `Lens`

Comment: @RobertHarvey I *want* to use record types, but I see a weakness in the language and much to be desired when I start using them in the context of unit tests. The fact that creating interfaces for everything is needed for unit tests also bothers me, but without them we spend a LOT more time in unit tests than we need to in opinion, and unit tests become a lot less useful when there's a crap ton of boilerplate I have to write, and start having to copy-pasta all over the place.

Comment: If I were on the C# team, I would have considered providing a mutable option for records, as in `mutable record MyRecord(...);`.

Comment: `with` expressions can be nested - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69449440/1301901

Comment: Sorry if you mentioned this somewhere, but, could you clarify: *why* is the `metadataParser` (or the `metadata` object in the second case) in the test? How does `sut.Create()` depend on these objects? Does it somehow call them internally (via some out-of-test wiring (or injection?)), does it indirectly depend on some result they produce, or what? E.g., what invokes `metadataParser.Deserialize()`? And how is it that in one version, the SUT appears to depend on  `metadataParser`, and on `metadata` in the other (is this just because you redesigned your classes in the second case)?

Answer (score 2):

> If the surface of this object and its properties changes later, this test will break even though those particular properties have nothing to do with what this test is trying to verify.

If you add a property, that amounts to a change of the public API of your method, so needing to change the unit test seem quite reasonable to me.

> Sort of a continuation of the above point: I have to create and pass in SonarrMetadata even though this type is inconsequential to the test.

If the tested method does not use `SonarrMetadata`, why include it in as a (indirect) parameter? *If* it is used by the tested method the test should supply a valid value. After all, it would be perfectly reasonable for the method to start by validating all the parameters.

Your unit tests should test the *public API* of your 'unit'. Note that the unit might be a single method, a class, some set of classes etc. All the prerequisites of the public API should be respected. If the public API of the unit changes, then the unit tests also need to change. If the public API is unchanged, the unit test should not need changing.

Keep in mind that unit tests should provide *value*, if you spend more time maintaining the tests than the tests save you, you need to change the way you write tests. Different types of methods benefit more or less from unit tests. Take a sorting algorithm for example, a unit test is very helpful to find of-by-one errors and other mistakes, and it is really easy to check the result. UIs on the other hand is notoriously difficult to automatically test, after all, the acceptance criteria might be something fluffy like "is easy to use for the average user".

My personal opinion is that you should try to minimize the usage of automatically generated Mocks, since they tend to be fairly fragile and more difficult to understand. If you have simple records without complex behavior I see no reason not to use them.

> Should I go with immutable types instead (add setters to the properties)?

Immutable types do not have setters, perhaps you mean *mutable* types? I would strongly prefer immutable types wherever practical, since they are easier to reason about, and records make immutable types fairly easy to use.

Comment: They are easier to reason about *in multi-threaded or multi-core contexts,* as they provide certain guarantees.  There are other ways to get easier reasoning, like pure functions.

Comment: However, the rest of your post is good, and I upvoted it.

Comment: In my view, adding a property shouldn't trigger all relevant tests that use an object to change. I may be testing one aspect of the behavior of something that does indeed accept the full object but the internal behavior is applied uniformly to all properties. In other words, the same assertions I apply to `CustomFormats` would also apply to `ReleaseProfiles`, but I don't want to duplicate the test assertions. Adding a property in this case, assuming that property is also consistently verified, shouldn't trigger a test failure for maintainability reasons.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would argue immutable objects are easier to reason about also in single threaded contexts, if for no other reason than they encourage things like pure functions. But 'wherever possible' might be to strong, perhaps 'wherever practical' would be better.

Comment: I tend to use unit tests to verify that my work and implementations are solid after I code something, while at the same time guarding against unintentional bugs due to refactoring later. Perhaps my motivations are misplaced, but so far it's proven valuable, if not a bit time consuming. In my experience, unit testing always slows down development but the value they provide is reducing the amount of unfound bugs in the future. I'm happy to be told I'm wrong, though, but that's just what has worked for me over the years.

Comment: @void.pointer I'm not entirely sure what your point is. If multiple test cases share prerequisites and assertions, move this to some methods shared by multiple tests. If your tests intentionally depend on the internal implementation details of your unit, then your test is inherently fragile and will need to be updated if those details change.

Comment: @void.pointer and I'm not arguing that *your* unit tests do not provide value. I'm arguing against the 'every line of code needs to be covered by unit test'-mentality that are proposed by some (not necessarily you). If your tests helps you save time/cost, great! keep writing them!

Comment: At the end of the day don't tests depend on implementation details? They are responsible for the post-conditions that our test assertions are based on. If those implementation details change, we must run the tests again to ensure that either 1) the post-conditions are not violated (tests pass) or that the tests are updated to verify changed post-conditions. Maybe I'm missing your point.

Comment: @void.pointer I would argue the test should depend on the *public API*. I.e. if I'm testing a sort method, I want to test that it actually sorts correctly, I don't care what algorithm is used. I *may* care about performance/memory usage, but that is probably better handled by  automated *benchmarking*. I would suggest watching [TDD, Where Did It All Go Wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZ05e7EMOLM), it is a bit old, but I found it informative.

Comment: @void.pointer it is also possible that you should test larger units. As an example, I made a system that took some piece of data and stored it in a document database. This was a fairly complex system, with multiple caching layers, splitting of data, manually stored index etc. Trying to test each class would be fragile, since the complexity caused fairly frequent changes. But testing the entire system was fairly easy, just mock the database-layer, store some data, and check that it can be retrieved.

Comment: In my case, I know that the implementation of my factory builds file paths that get inserted into the object that is returned. The purpose of this test is to verify that the file paths were normalized (use correct slashes) and other things. Basically, if the output isn't right here, other things will fail. So it's about finding any issues at the source. There's public API at all levels of granularity. In this case, the `Create()` method is `public`, so that's why I'm testing it. I've never found it particularly helpful when people say "don't test implementation", "test public API".

Comment: That's not a bash on your advice. I think it's more of an expressed frustration at my inability to see the point. But I think I'm violating intergalactic stack exchange law by continuing to discuss this with you. But I do want to thank you for your help and insight up to this point!